# Unable to load avro file to BigQuery because of schema mismatch

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I am new to big-query and i was trying to load  avro file to bigQuery table.For the first two times i was able to load avro file to bigquery table .For the third times onwords it starts failing and the error message is -

```
Waiting on bqjob_r77fb1a791c9ab204_0000015c88ab3ad8_1 ... (0s) Current 
status: DONE BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'xxx-yz-
df:bqjob_r77fb1a791c9ab204_0000015c88ab3ad8_1': Provided Schema does not 
match Table xxx-yz-df:adityadb.avro_poc3_part_stage$20120611.
```

i tried many times .How schema can be mismatch for the same file ,if you try more than two times .The load command which i was using is-

```
bq load --source_format=AVRO adityadb.avro_poc3_part_stage$20120611 gs://reair_ddh/apps/hive/warehouse/adityadb1.db/avro_poc3_part_txt/ingestion_time=20120611/000000_0
```

I dont know why this is happening,Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I looked at the job and it looks like field addr has changed mode from REPEATED to NULLABLE. Is this field an array or union in your Avro file? Array will become a REPEATED field in BigQuery, a union like [null, string] becomes a NULLABLE.

Comment: addr is struct here.if this issue is with REPEATED ,why it's allowing to load data for the two or three times.

Comment: This check is recently added for Avro. It has been there for other formats. I guess your previous queries hit the servers running the old version. When all servers are updated, REPEATED to NULLABLE will be disallowed consistently.

Comment: i was trying yesterday.sometimes data get loaded ,sometime not.when this check is added?

Comment: We started the roll out last week. It's still ongoing and some servers are still not updated yet.